# getting information from sphereCast's hit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know how to get information from a RayCast but couldn't find anything good on sphereCast.
When I shoot a raycast to an enemy I can detect it's health component and reduce it's health.

It's code:

```
    shootRay.origin = transform.position;
    shootRay.direction = transform.forward
    if (Physics.Raycast(shootRay, out shootHit, 100f, shootableMask))
    {
       EnemyHealth enemyHealth = shootHit.collider.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
        if (enemyHealth != null)
        {
            enemyHealth.TakeDamage(damagePerShot, shootHit.point);
        }
    }
```

Now I want to do a similar thing with SphereCast but instead of one enemy I want to detect all enemys in the hit area and reduce their health.

```
if (Physics.SphereCast(shootRay, 5f, out shootHit, 100f, shootableMask))
    {
       // ???
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this (http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/486261/how-can-i-raycast-to-multiple-objects.html) all you need to do is to use [RaycastAll](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastAll.html):

#### Example:

```
void Update() {
    RaycastHit[] hits;
    hits = Physics.RaycastAll(transform.position, transform.forward, 100.0F);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < hits.Length) {
        RaycastHit hit = hits[i];
        Renderer rend = hit.transform.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        if (rend) {
            rend.material.shader = Shader.Find("Transparent/Diffuse");
            rend.material.color.a = 0.3F;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i was thinking about an array but didn't know how to use it here.